# DuplicateFileException m4b + play services 9.0

Tags: android, google-play-services

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResFor'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml
>       File1:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\google-maps-sdk-m4b\jars\classes.jar
>       File2:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-basement\9.0.0\jars\classes.jar

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add below text in `build.gradle` inside the `android{}` section to solve the problem.

```
android {
...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude  'jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude  'build-data.properties'
     }
...
}
```

If getting more error DuplicateFileException add file with exclude.
Like :

Error

```
Duplicate files copied in APK jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml
```

Solution

```
exclude  'jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml'
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding this to your gradle file will solve your problem:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml'
}
```