# DuplicateFileException found of Csr305_annotations.gwt.xml in android

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml
>       File1: D:\Workspace\PNB-Copy Birla\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-basement\9.8.0\jars\classes.jar
>       File2: D:\Workspace\PNB-Copy Birla\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\PNB-Copy Birla\jwplayer-android-sdk\unspecified\jars\classes.jar

Please tell me how to remove this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37615242/duplicatefileexception-m4b-play-services-9-0

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following in your 'app' **build.gradle** file:

```
android {
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        ...
        exclude 'jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml'
    }
}
```